# Mongoose populates if findById(); does not populate if find()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Basically, Mongoose seems to populate an an array if I use **findById()**.populate(), but not if I use **find()**.populate(). I need to use findById()...

Any ideas why find().populate() doesn't seem to work?

Code snippet (express route):

```
//Retrieve a user's details, including their friends, for displaying.
app.get("/friends", function(req, res){

    //People.find({name: 'Tom'}).populate("friends").exec(function(err, foundUser){
    People.findById("5c37f2d67c8").populate("friends").exec(function(err, foundUser){

       console.log("! My friends: " + foundUser.friends);   //Is Undefined if using find()... but NOT if using findById(). Weird.

       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.redirect("/");
       } else {
           //res.send(foundUser);    //When I pass foundUser to the View, foundUser.friends is ALWAYS populated / never undefined, regardless of using find() or findUser(). Weird, as the above console.log() is undefined if using find(). 

           res.render("peopleIndex", {foundUser: foundUser}); 
       }        
    });
});
```

Edit: **SOLUTION**: If anyone's wondering, you can use findOne() instead of find() to get it to populate to pass to the view. (Still not sure why find() doesn't work.)

Comment: The ID is not valid, yes I know. Assume it works; i shortened / edited it when posting.

Comment: Solved using findOne() instead of find().

Comment: try using single quote inside populate . ie .populate('friends')  hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("! My friends: " + foundUser.friends);   
//Is Undefined if using find()... but NOT if using findById(). Weird.
```

what happens here is when using find() it gives you and array of objects not a single object so you can't use foundUser.friends.. instead try

```
console.log("! My friends: " + foundUser); // here it will give results
```

that's why your view contains regardless of you use find() or findById()

Comment: try answer now I think that should tell you what's wrong

Comment: Thanks, it prints out foundUser with friends. However later down the code, when trying to render, friends is undefined in the view. (Also, console.log(foundUser.friends) works (i.e. is not undefined) when using findById().populate()... Weird.

Comment: its because the way you access the object from the results check it

Comment: instead of findById() try using findOne()

Comment: findById() works, as does findOne() (as I"ve found about 10 minutes ago before your answer!)... Still not sure why find() doesn't work. Cheers.

Comment: find() gives an array so when chain populate() it refer the object that found   using the previous method(found object). So findOne() and findById() gives you single object while find() gives you an array so populate() crashes when using find() but not using findById() and  findOne() that's what happens

Comment: its like this when findOne().populate() or findById().populate() - u get {}.populate() but find().populate() - u get [].populate()... that's the reason ..hope this helped.. cheers